# How to distinguish between two derived classes from base pointer, without repeatedly trying dynamic_cast<> or enum field

Tags: c++, polymorphism

If i have a base class Base:

```
class Base {
public:
    bool foo;
    virtual bool bar() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
```

And two derived classes:

```
class Derived1 : public Base
{
    Derived1();
    bool bar() override;
}

class Derived2 : public Base
{
    Derived2();
    std::vector<baz*> bazVector;
    bool bar() override;
}
```

And i have a vector `std::vector<Base*> mainVector` which us populated like this:
`mainVector.push_back(someDerivedPointer)`

At some point i need to determine what object is stored: `Derived1` or `Derived2`, so i could access `Derived2->bazVector` if object is `Derived2`

One solution is trying to `dynamic_cast<Derived2>(mainVector.at(someIndex))` and check for returned `nullptr`, or storing some enum that would tell me what class this object belongs to, but these solutions seem crutchy, and i wonder if there is a better solution.

Comment: solution is to use polymorphism the right way. Override method and share common functionality. If you need to distinguish so badly between this pointers, maybe, they are not so similar.

In your case you could have a `getVector` that returns an empty vector for `Derived1` and the actual one for `Derived2`

Comment: What's wrong with adding virtual functions to your classes and just calling that/those? Each class object will call its *own* VF, so you can access the vector in the `Derived2` override.

Comment: You are doing that wrong. If you need do dynamic_cast for elements of container this means that abstract class is incorrectly designed or not up to date. Please provide more detail why you think you need this dynamic_cast then we can provide proper fix for your actual problem.

Comment: @Federico That seems to be the way, looks like i've implemented the base class wrong

Comment: You cannot distinguish it in any other way. And it is ill advised to write code that relies on distinguishing between Derived classes.

Comment: If you need objects that are "either `Derived1` or `Derived2`", not "something which is a `Base`", maybe you want `std::variant<Derived1, Derived2>` instead of `Base*`.

Comment: Or rather than a virtual `getVector`, maybe look at the function(s) which want to get it. Is the logic which contains "if it's a `Derived2` do something with `bazVector`" something which could make sense as a virtual function, with the `Derived2` override using its own `bazVector`?

Answer (score 0):

As advised in the comment section, you are probably looking the wrong direction.

There's high chance you are not tackling the problem with the right approach.
If you need to write different logic based on the actual derived class from a pointer, you are missing something.

We don't have too much details, but for what you said, you have two options:

1: adding a virtual method to retrieve your vector:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    bool foo;
    virtual bool bar() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual std::vector<baz*> getVector() = 0;
};
class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1();
    bool bar() override;    
    virtual std::vector<baz*> getVector() override {return {};};
}

class Derived2 : public Base
{
    std::vector<baz*> bazVector;
public:
    Derived2();
    bool bar() override;
    virtual std::vector<baz*> getVector() override {return bazVector;};
}
```

2: insert the logic where you need this vector into a virtual function (this is probably the better):

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    bool foo;
    virtual bool bar() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};
class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1();
    bool bar() override;    
    virtual void doSomething() override {/*no op*/};
}

class Derived2 : public Base
{
    std::vector<baz*> bazVector;
public:
    Derived2();
    bool bar() override;
    virtual void doSomething() override {/*do something with you bazVector*/};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is most likely the best way to go forward in OP's case, but considering how vague the question's title is, there is an alternative idiom that is sometimes useful when:

- All the derived classes of `Base` are known ahead of time.
- The derived classes are particularly heterogenous, and creating a lowest-common-denominator interface would be problematic in some way, shape, or form.

A good example of this would be an AST. clang's [`ASTConsumer`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTConsumer.html) uses a flavor of the technique.

The visitor. The basic idea is to have an external interface with virtual methods for each derived class, and have a single virtual function in `Base` that dispatches `this` to the correct function.

```
class Derived1;
class Derived2;

class Base {
public:
    class Visitor {
    public:
      virtual void operator()(Derived1&) {}
      virtual void operator()(Derived2&) {}
    protected:
      ~Visitor() = default;
    };
    
    virtual void visit(Visitor& v) = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
  public:
    Derived1(){}
    void visit(Base::Visitor& v) override { v(*this); }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
  public:
    Derived2(){}
    void visit(Base::Visitor& v) override { v(*this); }
};


// Usage example:
struct MyVisitor final : public Base::Visitor {
    void operator()(Derived1& obj) override {
        std::cout << "1\n";
    }
    
    void operator()(Derived2& obj) override {
        std::cout << "2\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> bases;
    bases.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived1>());
    bases.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived2>());

    MyVisitor v;
    for(auto& b : bases) {
        b->visit(v);
    }
}
```